# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera on a null object reference

Tags: android

i'm beginner, i want to develop a Google map Application in which i can search and select a place from autocomplete search , but when i click on any place then my App crash and display this error in the logcat please any one help me,

MainActivity Code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        switch(downloadType){
            case PLACES:
                // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                placesParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES);

                // Start parsing google places json data
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                placesParserTask.execute(result);

                break;

            case PLACES_DETAILS :
                // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                placeDetailsParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

                // Starting Parsing the JSON string
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                placeDetailsParserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>> implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    int parserType = 0;

    public ParserTask(int type){
        this.parserType = type;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<HashMap<String, String>> list = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            switch(parserType){
                case PLACES :
                    PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
                    // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                    list = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                    break;
                case PLACES_DETAILS :
                    PlaceDetailsJSONParser placeDetailsJsonParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();
                    // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                    list = placeDetailsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        switch(parserType){
            case PLACES :
                String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
                int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

                // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

                // Setting the adapter
                atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;
            case PLACES_DETAILS :
                HashMap<String, String> hm = result.get(0);

                // Getting latitude from the parsed data
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude from the parsed data
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lng"));

                // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of the activity_main.xml
                SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                // Getting GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
                fm.getMapAsync(this);

                LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
                CameraUpdate cameraZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(5);

                // Showing the user input location in the Google Map
               mMap.moveCamera(cameraPosition);
             mMap.animateCamera(cameraZoom);

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.position(point);
                options.title("Position");
                options.snippet("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);

                // Adding the marker in the Google Map
              mMap.addMarker(options);

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap=googleMap;
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.awais.mapapp1, PID: 13727
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference 
              at com.example.awais.mapapp1.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:332)
              at com.example.awais.mapapp1.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:262)
               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:664)
               at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:681)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
04-12 13:40:03.173 13727-13733/com.example.awais.mapapp1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.995ms
```

Comment: Start your AsyncTasks in ```onMapReady``` after you have a reference to the map.

Comment: @danypata sir how ? please suggest me i'm beginner i don't know

Comment: check if your LatLng Point is having some value or coming null.

Comment: LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
                    CameraUpdate cameraZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(5);
                    if(mMap!=null){
                        mMap.moveCamera(cameraPosition);
                        mMap.animateCamera(cameraZoom);
                    }

Comment: @Anmol null because i didn't provide any specific value

Answer (score 0):

Your mMap is being used before initialization.
Try this.

```
if(mMap!=null){
     mMap.moveCamera(cameraPosition);
                 mMap.animateCamera(cameraZoom);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's add some details here so you can understand better.

Your problem is caused by the fact that the map is not ready before the `AsyncTask` is executed and completed, which means that in the `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method the `mMap` is `null`.

So what to do ? Well depends on what you want.

1. If you really need the map in `onPostExecute`, the most simple way to be sure that the map is there, is by starting the `AsyncTask` after the map is ready (`onMapReady`).
2. If you don't care about the map updates, you can do a null-check in `onPostExecute`.

Now let's put some code:

First case:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap=googleMap;
    new DownloadTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); 
    //This is the correct way to start an async task, 
    //Also this is your first async task that I assume you execute
    for which you have the first onPostExecute.
    //The rest of the code should be ok with you.
}
```

If your first `onPostExecute` has to be done first you can store the variable that in the activity and check it when the map is ready or when the task is done. Something like this

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity { // maybe extend other activity
    private static final String RESULT_TYPE_PLACES = "places";
    private static final String RESULT_TYPE_PLACES_DETAILS = "places_details";
    private static final String RESULT_TYPE_UNKNOWN = "NAN";

    private String currentResult = RESULT_TYPE_UNKNOWN;

    //.....some code....

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result)
     currentResult = result;
     checkMapAndLoad();

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       mMap=googleMap;
       checkMapAndLoad():
    }

   private void checkMapAndLoad() {
     if(mMap != null && !RESULT_TYPE_UNKNOWN.equals(currentResult)) {
          new ParserTask(currentResult).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
     }
   }       
}
```